# How to get all the documents from an index in Redisearch?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redisearch

I am using RediSearch and storing the data in an Index through documents. I want to get all the documents from the Index, please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is half of an answer but perhaps it will spark a solution for you.

I can't speak to the Spring Data Redis part—not my jam—but in RediSearch itself you can get all the documents in the index by simply passing `*` as your query:

```
> FT.SEARCH my:index *
```